# grid column total using javascript asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to calculate grid column total on textchange in javascript.

How do I loop through the grid in javascript?

I added a handler to the `onblur` event of text box controls. I am able to get the row total on column change.

How do I get the column total on textbox change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Add `onblur` attribute to control on code behind and in javascript parse float controls and add the value like:

```
for(var i=0; i < GridRows; i++)
{
     TotalRH = parseFloat(TotalRH) + 
               parseFloat(document.getElementById('MainContent_gvGT_txtRegularHrs_' + i).value);            
     TotalOH = parseFloat(TotalOH) +
               parseFloat(document.getElementById('MainContent_gvGT_txtOverTimeHrs_' + i).value);
}
document.getElementById('MainContent_gvGT_txtTotalRegularHours').value = TotalRH;
document.getElementById('MainContent_gvGT_txtTotalOverTimeHours').value = TotalOH;
```